# Spring Transactions not working with @Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I have following code...

```
@Transactional (rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public String log(AuditRecord aRecord) throws AuditException {

    auditMaster(aRecord); //1. has an audit id and inserts into Audit table

    System.out.println(aRecord.getAuditId()); 

    if(true)
        throw new AuditException(Error.DUMMY_ERROR);

    auditSingleValued(aRecord); //2.

    auditMultiValued(aRecord); //3
}
```

The three auditXXX() Methods in the log function are inserting into different tables. As I have declared @Transactional on the log method I am expecting that the insert on auditMaster() method (at 1.) should be rolled back because of the exception in the if(true) block. But that is not happening, when I check my database it has the new Audit Id entry that the System.out.println is printing.

What can be made to achieve the rollback and make it a Atomic Transaction on the log() method as a whole?

Do I need to declare @Transacional on individual auditXXX methods as well?
My bean configuration has this entry...

```
 <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Do a proper transaction setup. Also what is `audtMaster` doing? Is it creating a new transaction? What is your database, does it actually support transactions (Mysql with MyISAM tables doesn't for instance).

Comment: auditMaster is using a jdbcTemplate and doing an insert. It does not have @Transactional on top of it. P.S. I edited my message.

Comment: `@Transactional` without `<tx:annotation-driven />` isn't going to do anything.

Comment: Thanks, works now. But my stack trace apart from my exception has Spring's AOP/Reflection/Transaction files blown up... hope that is all ok!